# How to find a pattern in string & replace in HTML Code

Tags: python, flask

I have HTML Code in a string variable. I want to modify this tag, from this:

`<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.jpg">3.jpg</a>`

to

`<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.jpg" download="3.jpg">3.jpg</a>`, basically add "`download="3.jpg"`

I want to do this, with all links that have `.jpg`,`.png`,`.gif`,`.jpeg`,`.mp4` extension at the end.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just to help you out..Check `find` function, get the index and then insert

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I would love to try different things, but no idea where to start

Comment: You can start with "Beautiful Soup".

Answer (score 0):

There might be easier ways to accomplish this, but I think one way to start could be using `regex`. Define a pattern to find all of the file endings. Then fetch the file-name (e.g., `3.jpg`) to compile a string that `.replace()`s the first pattern. Like this:

```
import re 
# all possible formats you mentioned:
html = ['<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.jpg">3.jpg</a>',
'<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.png">3.png</a>',
'<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.gif">3.gif</a>',
'<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.jpeg">3.jpeg</a>',
'<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.mp4">3.mp4</a>']
# regex patterns (everything within paranthesis is going to be extracted
regex1 = re.compile(r'(\.jpg\"|\.png\"|\.gif\"|\.jpeg\"|\.mp4\")')
regex2 = re.compile(r'\/images\/(.*?)\.')
# iterate over the strings
for x in html:
  if regex1.search(x): # if pattern is found:
    # find and extract
    a = regex1.search(x).group(1)
    b = regex2.search(x).group(1)
    # compile new string by replacing a
    new = x.replace(a, f'{a} download="{b + a}')
    print(new)
```

This gives you:

```
<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.jpg" download="3.jpg">3.jpg</a>
<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.png" download="3.png">3.png</a>
<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.gif" download="3.gif">3.gif</a>
<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.jpeg" download="3.jpeg">3.jpeg</a>
<a href="/fileszzr/images/3.mp4" download="3.mp4">3.mp4</a>
```

If you want to learn more on `regex`, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).
Also, note that f-strings (as in `f'{a} download="{b + a}'`) are supported in python version >3.6.